# How do I memoize my backtracking algorithms and make use of dynamic programming?

Tags: dynamic-programming, backtracking, memoization

So I've managed to come up with some solutions to the following problems using backtracking. The problem is that they either get bottom 5% in terms of speed or I just run out of time.

They all follow a very familiar pattern in that they all use a closure `backtrack` function. This just happens to be my backtracking style and I'm very comfortable with this approach. I'm wondering if there's a way for me to memoize the solutions with just a few lines of code or if I have to completely rethink my brute force approach. I think the thing that I'm struggling with the most here is the shape of the memo data structure for each problem.

Note that I'm familiar with memoizing something as simple as the fibonacci sequence. Thanks! I think if I can get some help on this I'll be able to really take my problem solving to the next level.

https://leetcode.com/problems/word-break-ii/

```
var wordBreak = function(s, wordDict) {
  const results = [];
  const backtrack = (prefix, remaining, result) => {
    if (!remaining.length) {
      results.push(result.slice(0, -1));
    }
    const appending = remaining.slice(0, 1);
    remaining = remaining.slice(1, remaining.length);
    if (wordDict.includes(prefix + appending)) {
      backtrack('', remaining, result + prefix + appending + ' ');
    }
    if (remaining) {
      backtrack(prefix + appending, remaining, result);
    }
  }
  backtrack('', s, '');
  return results;
};
```

https://leetcode.com/problems/coin-change/

```
var coinChange = function(coins, amount) {
  let min = Infinity;
  const backtrack = (result, target) => {
    if (target === 0) {
      min = Math.min(result.length, min);
    }
    let i = coins.length - 1;
    while (i >= 0) {
      if (coins[i] <= target) {
        backtrack([...result, coins[i]], target - coins[i]);
      }
      i--;
    }
  };

  backtrack([], amount);
  if (min === Infinity) return -1;
  return min;
}
```

https://leetcode.com/problems/jump-game/

```
var canJump = function(nums) {
  let flag = false;
  const target = nums.length - 1;
  const backtrack = index => {
    if (index === target) {
      flag = true;
      return;
    }
    if (nums[index]) {
      let n = nums[index];
      while (n > 0) {
        backtrack(index + n);
        n--;
      }
    }
  }
  backtrack(0);
  return flag;
};
```

https://leetcode.com/problems/palindrome-partitioning/

```
var partition = function(s) {
  const results = [];
  const backtrack = (prefix, str, result) => {
    if (!str.length) {
      results.push(result);
      return;
    }
    const arr = str.split('');
    prefix += arr.shift();
    if (prefix.length === 1 || isPalindrome(prefix)) {
      backtrack('', arr.join(''), [...result, prefix]);
    }
    if (arr.length) {
      backtrack(prefix, arr.join(''), [...result]);
    }
  }

  const isPalindrome = str =>
    str === str.split('').reverse().join('');

  backtrack('', s, []);
  return results;
};
```